# Writing generic code to construct tuples and namedtuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do something like this:

```py
def apply_foo(data):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        return type(data)(apply_foo(x) for x in data)
    return foo(data)
```

I use `type(data)` to construct the same concrete list/tuple subclass the user passed in. However, this code does not work with namedtuples. I would have to construct the namedtuple via `type(data)(*(foo(x) for x in data))`. But, I do not know the exact namedtuple class in advance (since the user can pass in anything), so I can't check the type explicitly.

Is there a clean way for me to generically accept any type of list/tuple while supporting namedtuples for this method?

Comment: This operation might not make sense in the first place. namedtuples are fundamentally heterogeneous data structures, even more so than regular tuples - each element represents a different kind of thing. There aren't a lot of cases where it makes sense to apply the same function to every element of a namedtuple, or to build the same kind of namedtuple out of the return values.

Comment: For example, if your namedtuple is `Person('bob', 15)` with fields `name` and `age`, there aren't a lot of possible `foo` functions where it makes sense to build the namedtuple `Person(foo('bob'), foo(15))`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica this is a great point. In my specific use case, data is a nested list/tuple/other of tensors (PyTorch). "foo" copies them to the appropriate device from the host. namedtuples allow you to write self-documenting code (e.g. a simple example could be a namedtuple with an image and a label for classification).

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution:

```py
def apply_foo(data):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        try:
            return type(data)(apply_foo(x) for x in data)
        except TypeError:
            return type(data)(*(apply_foo(x) for x in data))
    return foo(data)
```

Some nice properties of this solutions are that we don't need to use introspection techniques (e.g. `inspect`) or rely on the private members of namedtuples (e.g. `_fields`). Also, `apply_foo` is only called once per data member, since generators are lazy, so there is no wasted computation.

The downside of this solution is that we need to rely on exceptions, so if there is an unrelated `TypeError` when we do `type(data)(apply_foo(x) for x in data)`, our method will obscure the error to the user.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you need a check to see if the object is iterable. also you can use check on any of the types described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

```
import collections.abc as abc

def check(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (abc.Iterable)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

check for some types:

```
from collections import namedtuple

nt = namedtuple('Example' , 'a b')

values = [
    None, True, 1, 1.5, 1+1j, [1],
    (1,), range(0), "1", b"1",
    bytearray("1", "utf-8"), {1:1}, {1},
    frozenset([1]), nt(1, True)
]


for i in values:
    result = check(i)
    print(type(i), result)
```

here is the output:

```
<class 'NoneType'> False
<class 'bool'> False
<class 'int'> False
<class 'float'> False
<class 'complex'> False
<class 'list'> True
<class 'tuple'> True
<class 'range'> True
<class 'str'> True
<class 'bytes'> True
<class 'bytearray'> True
<class 'dict'> True
<class 'set'> True
<class 'frozenset'> True
<class '__main__.Example'> True
```

Here are also other (not so elegant) ways to achieve this:

```
def check2(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def check3(obj):
    try:
        getattr(obj, "__iter__")
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

this is obviously not all methods, but the above is enough

Comment: The problem is the constructor signatures, not detecting iterability.